# Share cookies between two application with same domain but different port

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am working on SSO with OAuth2 and it's working fine, but I want to do single logout (log out from all application), for that I want to share a cookie set by auth server (app1) which is accessed by client (app2) and (app3).

Below what I tried

http://127.0.0.1:8080/app1

```
@GetMapping("/principal")
public Principal user(Principal principal,HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("principalName", "anil");
    cookie.setDomain("127.0.0.1");
    cookie.setPath("/");//<-- important
    cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    return principal;
}
```

http://127.0.0.1:8081/app2 or http://127.0.0.1:8082/app3

Getting in app2

```
 System.out.println("principalName----"+WebUtils.getCookie(httpServletRequest,  "principalName"));
```

Comment: And what did you get? BTW, it seems that all applications are on the **same** port.

Comment: Edited -its showing null, after debugging I only found jsessionid in cookies, "principalName" cookie not found in the client application.